# Array function (image processing project)

Tags: c, visual-studio, image-processing

I faced an  issue of my assignment  related the array function.
I want to make a border element with '0' at first three and last three rows and columns. Firstly , I able to generate the number of 256X256 size (array[256][256]).
Then, after the first array  I generated that I need to do some condition .For example,

- For element value <127, subtract 20 from the value.
- For element value >127, add 20 to the value.
- If the value of any element is <0 after the operation then assign the value 0 to it.
- If the value of any element is >255 after the operation then assign the value 255 to
  it.

The problem is when I generated again, the "0" border of element become different. How to i solve it to be like first array as seen like "0" border of element?

[image]

Below is my C++ code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int inputimage[256][256], modifinputimage[256][256];
    int i, j;
    char ch;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (i < 3)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if (j < 256)
                {
                    printf("0\t");
                }

            }
        }
        else if (i >= 253)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if (j < 256)
                {
                    printf("0\t");
                }

            }
        }
        else if (i >= 3 && i <253)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if ((i >= 3 && j < 3) || (i<253 && j >= 253))
                {
                        printf("0\t");
                }


                if (j >= 3 && j < 253)
                {
                    inputimage[i][j] = rand() % 256;
                    printf("%d\t", inputimage[i][j]);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    printf("\nProceed to Contrast Adjustment ? (Press ENTER to continue)*** \n\n\n\n");
    ch = getche();

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (i < 3)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if (j < 256)
                {
                    printf("0\t");
                }

            }
        }
        else if (i >= 253)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if (j < 256)
                {
                    printf("0\t");
                }

            }
        }
        else if (i >= 3 && i <253)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                if ((i >= 3 && j < 3) || (i<253 && j >= 253))
                {
                    printf("0\t");
                }


                if (j >= 3 && j < 253)
                {
                    if (inputimage[i][j] < 127 && inputimage[i][j] >= 20)
                    {
                        modifinputimage[i][j] = inputimage[i][j] - 20;
                        printf("%1d\t", modifinputimage[i][j]);
                    }
                    if (inputimage[i][j] > 127 && inputimage[i][j] <= 235)
                    {
                        modifinputimage[i][j] = inputimage[i][j] + 20;
                        printf("%1d\t", modifinputimage[i][j]);
                    }
                    if (inputimage[i][j] <= 0)
                    {

                        modifinputimage[i][j] = inputimage[i][j];
                        printf("0\t");
                    }
                    if (inputimage[i][j] >= 255)
                    {

                        modifinputimage[i][j] = inputimage[i][j];
                        printf("255\t");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: C++? It's pure C. But even in C it's `int main`.

Comment: Yes,this is just pure C. But i still cant solve my problem.Border element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modification you need to use the approach of accessing the array by rows and columns by using two for loops at the start to have the position of both row and column. For Example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++){


    }
}
```

this way you are going through all the rows and columns and inside the above condition use

```
if(i <= 3 || i >= 253){
  //here u can use the nested loop to print 0's for both first and last 3 rows
     printf("0\t");
}

// similarly for columns you can use this 

else if(j <= 3 || j >=253){

     printf("0\t");
}

else if(i > 3 && i < 253 && j > 3 && j < 253){
  //here your modification rules
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thx for help .According the way u share me but i still face same issue.

Comment: only these Frst and last row are ok .but frst and last columns still cant be 0